# How can I extract content of a specific div from a webpage?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I want to load content of a specific div with `class='box'` from a webpage, and I used Simple HTML DOM for this. but I can't write a clear pattern for `preg_match`, here is my `php` code:

```
<?php
   $url = "http://www.example.com/pages/";
   $page_all = file_get_contents($url); 

   preg_match(...?);


   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($div_array[0]);
   echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Please help me to write a right pattern for `preg_match`

Comment: I don't get it - If you're using Simple HTML DOM, then you don't need a regex. Your sample code does not reference Simple HTML DOM at all.

Comment: @nickb you say that I have not forced to use `simple_html_dom`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleHtmlDOM :

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();

// Load from a string
$html->load('<html><body><p>Hello World!</p><p>We're here</p></body></html>');

// Load a file
$html->load_file('http://net.tutsplus.com/');

# get an element representing the second paragraph  
$element = $html->find("div[class=box1]");

#access HTML attr
$element->innertext .= "Somthing";

#save and echo
echo $element->save();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,I'll try it. (mamnoonan dooste aziz)

Comment: Thanks, It worked well. (Persian: mamnoon dooste aziz javab dad, khoshhalam ke toonestam too stack be zaboone khodam benevisam, english ham neveshtam ke downvote nadan ye vaght) @Mr-Moqadam

Comment: @MeghdadHadidi : Thanks (khahesh mikonam.khoshhalam karet rah oftad.che hali mide inja farsi minvisi :) )

Answer (score 1):

You should check out: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

An example would be:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();

$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/pages/');

$ret = $html->find('div[class=box]');
```

Don't waste your time with Regex, there are tools for the job.